# WebRequest timeout from Windows Service and Server

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Currently we have a Windows Service which processes messages from RabbitMQ. It does this by using a web request to a URi. We then read the response and then proceed from there if it is successful.

**Process Messages Method**

```
//Deserialze the response 
PMResponse res = (PMResponse)ser.ReadObject(GetResponse(addr + paramArgs));
```

**GetResponse Method**

```
private static MemoryStream GetResponse(string URi)
            {
            // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(URi);
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = "POST";

            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            string postData = "";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            // Get the request stream.
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close();

            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();


            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Display the content.
            //Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);


            MemoryStream mStrm = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseFromServer));
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            return mStrm;
        }
```

The service is installed on one of our servers where, last week out of nowhere, the application stopped processing messages.

The web service we use to process the SMS messages works fine when we open the parameterised URL in the web browser.

The service also works on my local machine. However when deployed on the server either as a service or as a test console application the operation times out.

What problems do you think there are? The code works, just not on this server.

Comment: Can you open the url from a browser on that actual server?

Comment: Yes I can Daniel. From the browser it works as it should, from the application on the server it times out. From the application on my local machine it works fine.

Comment: If it works locally and all app data is the same.then sounds like a networking problem. Have you used Fiddler or anything like that to view traffic?

Comment: As a side note: there is a C# RabbitMQ client that will do a lot of this work for you so you can focus on handling the messages instead of the networking aspects.

Comment: I'll tell the team that we should look into it. The service we have works fine at he moment. The problem is resolved, the company we use for sending the SMS restarted their servers and it worked fine. Many man hours wasted on this before it even got to me hah. Thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to save people time:
"The problem is resolved, the company we use for sending the SMS restarted their servers and it worked fine. Many man hours wasted on this before it even got to me hah. Thanks for your time guys."